# Attributes inserted with null values with GORM 6.0.12

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.5

When I am creating a simple object and just calling save method on that object, all the attributes which are nullable true are inserted into the database with null value.
This is just creating clutter in the database.
Is there a way to avoid this?

> 1. Grails version - 2.5.6
> 2. GORM version - 6.0.12
> 3. mongodb.engine = "mapping"

Domain :

```
    public class Person {
        static constraints = {
            name(nullable: true)
            telecom(nullable: true)
            gender(nullable: true)
            birthDate(nullable: true)
            address(nullable: true)
        }

    }
```

Code :

```
Person person = new Person()
person.save()
```

Mongo db entry

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(59),
    "address" : null,
    "birthDate" : null,
    "gender" : null,
    "name" : null,    
    "telecom" : null,
    "version" : 0,
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2020-04-18T15:34:26.244Z"),
    "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2020-04-18T15:34:26.244Z")
}
```

Expected Entry in database :

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(59),
    "version" : 0,
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2020-04-18T15:34:26.244Z"),
    "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2020-04-18T15:34:26.244Z")
}
```

This used to work with the older versions of GORM, this was the default behaviour, but when I updated the version of GORM, I started getting all these null values in the database, which is just increasing the size of my database.

Comment: "...all the attributes which are nullable true are inserted into the database with null value... Is there a way to avoid this?" - What do you want to be inserted into the database for `null` properties?

Comment: Expectation : 
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(59),
    "version" : 0,
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2020-04-18T15:34:26.244Z"),
    "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2020-04-18T15:34:26.244Z")
}

Comment: Right.  I didn't read closely enough and didn't realize you were using Mongo before the question edit.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - Can you help me with this problem, or is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: What will happen if you use `Person.collection.insertOne([_id:'the-id'],[telecom:null])`?